# How to set line markers in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, linechart, markers

I would like to set different markers to the various series plotted in my chart. How do I go about doing this since the various series are plotted only when the user selects that particular option. I currently have 7 series that can be plotted.

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= loop - 1; i++) {
 Chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
 Chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 5; }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145837/charting-markers-not-appearing-on-line

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's
[System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or 
[System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can set it:

1. For each point in your series' `DataPointCollection`.
2. For the whole `Series` ([DataPointCustomProperties.MarkerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.markerstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

If you are using `MarkerStyle.None` you can also use a `MarkerImage` instead of the default predefined markers, same remarks as above, it should work for the whole series or any point. You can even manipulate those values directly with [DataPointCustomProperties.SetCustomProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.setcustomproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [DeleteCustomProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.deletecustomproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like:

```
dataPoint.SetCustomProperty("MarkerStyle", MarkerStyle.Circle);
```

or

```
dataPoint.DeleteCustomProperty("MarkerStyle");
```

Then, make sure:

1. you have a big enough value for the `MarkerSize` property so that your points are visible.
2. marker color differs from background
3. chart type supports markers.